# Creating UI with two jQuery DataTables and moving around record between them

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatable, datatables

First of all, I can't post jsfiddle as a link in my question, that's why i posted link as normal text.

I designed a user interface with two jQuery DataTable.

First table loads with initial data and second table loads with no data.

When the user clicks on a row or selecting a raw and click on move button, i just transferring data from first table to second and vice versa.

Also i am maintaining two array for final data in first and second table, to submit to the server.

This is the UI - jsfiddle.net/viswa317/d7R7c/3/embedded/result/

This is the code - jsfiddle.net/viswa317/d7R7c/3/

Problem is that removed row or tr tag is coming back, just play with that ui you can understand what i mean.

I am removing user selected row or tr tag using Jquery `remove()` function, but when i move data from second to first table, Already removed data in first table is coming back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, using Jquery `remove` function not really removing the row. It just removing the tr tag as we expect from jquery, so i am using DataTabel `fnDeleteRow` function. It's working perfectly.

For the code and ui use the same links i posted in question, I updated with working code.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly not use the jquery sortable plugin? For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470775/using-jquery-ui-sortable-with-html-tables)

Then all you have to do is connect the two tables and you have drag and drop functionality. Although this example uses lists and not tables, [This](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) is what is possible