# Drag and dropping columns PHP, JS, how can that be done?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I was able to get the rows to be drag and dropped within the table, but I am having difficulty with the columns. My bellow javascript doesn't seem to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
<?php


if(!$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")) {
     echo "Cannot connect to db server";
}
elseif(!mysql_select_db("Disney")) {
     echo "Cannot select database";
}
else {
     if(!$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DisneyCharacters")) {
          echo "Cannot parse query";
     }
     elseif(mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0) {
          echo "No records found";
     }
     else {
//      Name, Movie, year, ShoeSize, FavoriteColor, FavoriteFood, PhoneNumber, CharacterType, FavoriteDrink, Address, FavortieTvShow, School, Age, HouseSqFoot, RelationShip, Rating, CarModel, CarYear, Boyfriend,
// NumberFriends, CriminalHistory, HappyEnding, FavoriteLocation, AppleDevice, WorkLocation, Weight, RepublicanDemocratic, DressColor, Shampoo, NumberKids) 

          echo "<table  width=\"400\" height=\"1\" id=\"sortedtable\" class=\"bordered\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n";
          echo "<thead>\n<tr>";
          echo "<th>Name  </th>";
          echo "<th>Movie  </th>";
          echo "<th>Year  </th>";
          echo "<th>Shoe Size </th>";
          echo "<th>Favorite Color </th>";
          echo "<th>Favorite Food </th>";
          echo "<th>Phone Number </th>";
          echo "<th>Character Type </th>";
          echo "<th>Favorite Drink </th>";
          echo "<th>Address </th>";
          echo "<th>Favorite TvShow </th>";
          echo "<th>School </th>";
          echo "<th>Age </th>";
          echo "<th>HouseSqFoot </th>";
          echo "<th>Relationship </th>";
          echo "<th>Rating </th>";
          echo "<th>Car Model </th>";
          echo "<th>Car Year </th>";
          echo "<th>Boyfriend </th>";
          echo "<th>Number Friends </th>";
          echo "<th>Criminal History </th>";
          echo "<th>Happy Ending </th>";
          echo "<th>Favorite Location </th>";
          echo "<th>Apple Device </th>";
          echo "<th>Work Location </th>";
          echo "<th>Weight</th>";
          echo "<th>Republican Democratic </th>";
          echo "<th>Dress Color </th>";
          echo "<th>Shampoo </th>";
          echo "<th>Number Kids </th>";
echo "</tr>\n</thead>\n";


          echo " <tbody>";
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {


               echo "<tr>
                    <td>$row[Name]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[Movie]&nbsp&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[Year]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[ShoeSize]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[FavoriteColor]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[FavoriteFood]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[PhoneNumber]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[CharacterType]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[FavoriteDrink]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[Address]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[FavoriteTvShow]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[School]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[Age]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[HouseSqFoot]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[RelationShip]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[Rating]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[CarModel]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[CarYear]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[Boyfriend]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[NumberFriends]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[CriminalHistory]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[HappyEnding]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[FavoriteLocation]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[AppleDevice]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[WorkLocation]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[Weight]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[RepublicanDemocratic]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[DressColor]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[Shampoo]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[NumberKids]&nbsp</td>
                </tr>\n";



          }
           echo " </tbody>";
          echo "</table><br />\n";
     }

}
?>
```

///JavaScript

```
// Drag and drop rows
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sortedtable").tablesorter({
        sortList: [
            [0, 0],
            [2, 1]
        ],
        widgets: ['zebra']
    });
    $("tbody").sortable();
    $("tbody").disableSelection();
});


//Drag and drop columns 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sortedtable").tablesorter({
        sortList: [
            [0, 0],
            [2, 1]
        ],
        widgets: ['zebra']
    });
    $("thead").sortable();
    $("thead").disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: No, i do not use the console, i use BBEdit! and run it on my localhost to see the output. I think my thinking is correct, but its not interchanging the columns

Comment: and how you debugging the javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library DataTables. It provides a lot more than you ask but is easy to use and highly configurable