# Table Sorting in HTML in reference to Date and Time

Tags: java, html

I have a table that i wish to put in order (referencing the date and time). I currently have

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Contents of /media/Audio/Backup Recordings/</TITLE>
    <style type="text/css">filelist { visibility: hidden; }</style>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <B>Contents of /media/Audio/Backup Recordings/</B>
    <P />
    <TABLE>
        <TR>
            <TD>Type</TD>
            <TD>Name</TD>
            <TD>Size</TD>
            <TD>Time</TD>
            <TD>Hash</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>File</TD>
            <TD>
                <A HREF="XXXXXXXXX">Backup_Test_2017-03-14_11-22-27.mp3</A>
            </TD>
            <TD>646272</TD>
            <TD>Tue Mar 14 11:23:07 2017</TD>
            <TD>---</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>File</TD>
            <TD>
                <A HREF="XXXXXXXXX">Backup_Test_2_2017-03-13_09-15-00.mp3</A>
            </TD>
            <TD>14402304</TD>
            <TD>Tue Mar 13 09:30:00 2017</TD>
            <TD>---</TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <P />
    Up to 
    <A HREF="YYYYYYYYY">parent directory</A>
    <P />
    <filelist bytes_available="2485193728">
        <directory read_only="true">
            <name>..</name>
            <media_path>Audio</media_path>
        </directory>
        <file hidden="false">
            <name>Backup_Test_2017-03-14_11-22-27.mp3</name>
            <size>646272</size>
            <time>Tue Mar 14 11:23:07 2017</time>
            <hash></hash>
            <media_path>Audio/Backup Recordings/Backup_Test_2017-03-14_11-22-27.mp3</media_path>
        </file>
        <file hidden="false">
            <name>Backup_Test_2_2017-03-13_09-15-00.mp3</name>
            <size>14402304</size>
            <time>Tue Mar 13 09:30:00 2017</time>
            <hash></hash>
            <media_path>Audio/Backup Recordings/Backup_Test_2_2017-03-13_09-15-00.mp3</media_path>
        </file>
    </filelist>
</BODY>
```

Is there a way to order the table so that the March 13 entry (Backup test) appears before March 14 (Backup Test 2)? I wish to add hundreds of recordings and automatically sort depending on date and time.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470775/using-jquery-ui-sortable-with-html-tables

Answer (score 0):

You can find this

Requirements: jquery

```
var rows = $('TABLE TR:nth-child(n+2)')
rows.sort(function(a,b){
var a =new Date($(a).find("td:nth-child(4)").text())
var b =new Date($(b).find("td:nth-child(4)").text())

if (a>b)
{
    return 1
}else
{
    return -1
}

})
$('TABLE TR:nth-child(n+2)').remove()
$('TABLE').append(rows)
```

As I found that your first row is header. so the retrieve, sorting and appending are after the first row.