# Sortable rows in javascript or Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript file which outputs a table with some items on the fly,
and i want to make them sortable by dragging and dropping them to another order.

i have looked up the JQuery UI library but i can't find how to apply the library to my app.

```
  static addBookToList(book){
    const list = document.querySelector('.book-list');
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML = `
    <td>${book.title}</td>
    <td>${book.author}</td>
    <td>${book.isbn}</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-med delete">x</a></td>
   `;


   list.appendChild(row);
 }
```

this will add a table of books to a list (which i want to be sortable)

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?  It doesn't look like you've attempted to use JQuery UI at all yet.

Comment: you can read [sortable with html tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470775/using-jquery-ui-sortable-with-html-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that u have loaded all jquery ui libraries

then

```
$(function() {
   $("tr").draggable();
});
```

Comment: That just allows you to drag it around the page.  This won't snap, sort or anything.